# Generating a record for each instance of a weekly time slot in a MySQL table between two dates using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to do the following:

I have a MySQL table which contains time slots (stored as SQL Dates) that a client regularly has meetings at each week, e.g. Monday at 13.00, Monday at 14.00, Tuesday at 15.00, etc.  Each time slot is unique, and there is only one entry per time slot (i.e. the table contains data for a 'sample' week).

I would like to generate a list of all the weekly time slots that fall between two specified dates, sorted by time slot, using PHP.

So, for instance, if I had just the above three time slots in the table and I wanted all of the slots that fell between 1 Jan 2013 and 15 Jan 2013, the script would return:

```
1 Jan 2013 15.00
7 Jan 2013 13.00
7 Jan 2013 14.00
8 Jan 2013 15.00
14 Jan 2013 13.00
14 Jan 2013 14.00
15 Jan 2013 15.00
```

I could add the code that I currently have, but I get the feeling it really wouldn't help matters, as I've got into quite a muddle over this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: forget my first answer, I misunderstood your question. I didn't realise that you want to create a weekly repetition of the records in your timeslot table.

So here is a very different solution. It's only partial, but it might help you a bit. Your problem is that you want sorted output. If you loop over the rows in your table in an outer loop, and then loop over the date range in an inner loop, you end up with the wrong sort order.

To avoid that, we can switch the loops: loop over the date range in the outer loop, and loop over the timeslots in the inner loop. The problem with that though, is that you should avoid repeatedly requesting the same data from your mysql database, that would slow things down unnecessarily.

A solution is to extract the timeslots from the database once, and store it in an array. Then use the date range as the outer loop. The alternative solution is to loop over the rows in your database table in the outer loop, but not echo the results immediately, instead add them to an array and sort the array afterwards. If you store the UNIX dates (not the formatted dates) then sorting is easy.

Anyway, here is a possible solution using the first approach. The only remaining bit for you is to create the $timeslots array-of-associative-arrays from your timeslots table.

```
# $timeslots is an array of associative arrays.
# The trick is to extract this data from your mysql table

$timeslots = array( 
    # Timeslot corresponding to Monday 15:00
    array ( 'dow' => 1, 'hour' => 15 ),
    # Tuesday 13:00
    array ( 'dow' => 2, 'hour' => 13 ),
);

$date = 1356998400; // '2013-01-01';
$end_date = 1358208000; // '2013-01-15';

while($date <= $end_date)
{
    # Convert the loop variable to day of week              
    $date_dow = date('w', $date); 

    foreach ($timeslots as $timeslot)
    {
        # Check if it matches the one in the timeslot
        if ($date_dow == $timeslot['dow'])
        {
            $timeofday = $date + (3600 * $timeslot['hour']);
            echo date("D, j M Y H:i", $timeofday) . '<br>';
        }

    }
    $date += 86400; # advance one day
}
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
Tue, 1 Jan 2013 13:00
Mon, 7 Jan 2013 15:00
Tue, 8 Jan 2013 13:00
Mon, 14 Jan 2013 15:00
Tue, 15 Jan 2013 13:00
```

Comment: You can use [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse it.

Comment: @amarillion Thanks. My dates are stored are SQL Dates, so that helps.  However the SQL table does not contain all of the time slots that I want to return. Rather it contains the timeslots over the course of one (sample) week, and I want to return all the slots, at these times of the week, that fall between two dates.  I hope this is clearer!

Comment: I have added some more detail to the question to hopefully help clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: Indeed, I completely misunderstood. Hopefully my second answer is more useful.

Comment: @amarillion Thanks.  That's working better.  I am still not sure how to expand this though. If I loop through every entry in the table, then I can get all of the time slots between dates, but they are not sorted in date order, but rather are grouped according to time slot.  I need all the time slots listed together, in date order.

Comment: @amarillion Thanks, that's very helpful, and set me on the right track.